# Can Samsung T3 SSD run under Linux?

Tags: linux, ssd, external-drive

1- It's foramtted as exFAT and needs to be activated by Windows first prior to use. As frustrating as this may be, I'm willing to deal with it if it will work fully under Linux afterwards. So is it compatible with Linux?

2- I assume I can repartition the drive to run a Linux distro on one partition and store my data on the other partition, is this correct?

3- If I plan the set up in my 2nd point, can I use LUKS Full Disk Encryption when installing the OS; what will happen to my Data partition?

4- What is the Hardware Encryption option advertised with Samsung T3 SSD? Will it take affect using a Linux Distro?

Comment: This question is likely to be seen as too broad.  Generally, the site's model is for each question to be a single question.  You could probably get away with 1 & 2 in one question, and 3 & 4 in another since the pairs are closely related.

Comment: I honestly expected this, but it doesn't make sense. They are all about SSDs with specific use case scenario (using under Linux and running Linux). EDIT: I just made it more specific.